# Как записать JSON объект из JavaScript в JSON файл?

Tags: javascript, python, json, tauri

Всем привет!
Пишу мини-программу на Tauri. В этой программе есть `form` из которой, при нажатии на кнопку, принимаются данные в JSON объект. Далее, мне необходимо эти данные передать в python скрипт.

У меня был такой вариант, что бы этот объект записывался из JS скрипта, в JSON файл и уже из него, python скрипт бы уже читал данные. Но, как оказывается, просто так JS не умеет записывать данные в файлы.

```
<form class="contact-form">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Полное ФИО">
      <input type="text" name="area" placeholder="Район">
      <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Город">
      <input type="text" name="day" placeholder="День">
      <input type="text" name="month" placeholder="Месяц">
      <input type="text" name="year" placeholder="Год">
      <input type="text" name="street" placeholder="Улица">
      <input type="text" name="house" placeholder="Дом">
      <input type="text" name="housing" placeholder="Строение / Корпус">
      <input type="text" name="apartment" placeholder="Квартира">
      <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

```
function handleFormSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  const data = new FormData(event.target);
  
  const formJSON = Object.fromEntries(data.entries());
  
  console.log(JSON.stringify(formJSON, null, 2))
}

const form = document.querySelector('.contact-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', handleFormSubmit);
```

На данный момент, скрипт исправно выдает результат в консоль. Вопрос в том, как это передать в python скрипт

[image]

Comment: Ну например, пишите на Python rest сервис (flask, fastapi), который через http запросы будет получать данные.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, tauri - это создание десктопного приложения - ну не может там не быть записи файла на диск.

Comment: https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/fs